# Count the result from a loop and if statement

Tags: java

I have an array of numbers which I am looping through to find numbers equal to 90 or greater than 90. My current code prints each number that matches the criteria (they are 91, 93, 93, 96, 97) but instead, I would like to count how many numbers match the criteria and print that instead (in this case it would be 5). How would I go about achieving this?

My code is as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
    if (scores[i] == 90 | scores[i] > 90) {
        System.out.println(scores[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can rewrite `scores[i] == 90 | scores[i] > 90` as `scores[i] >= 90`

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think of that shorthand.

Comment: Right.  You may also be unaware of the difference between `||` and `|` for boolean expressions.  If you use `||`, then the right hand side won't be evaluated if the left hand side returns true. In most cases, that's preferable to using `|`, which always evaluates both sides.

Comment: @DavidWallace, so when we use `|` ,  only if left hand and right side evaluates to true, the control goes inside. is it? Also what is the name of `|` operator in java

Comment: @prash No you have misunderstood me.  If you use `|`, then the condition will still be true if either half of it is true.  It's just that both will be evaluated.  So `|` and `||` give the same outcome - it's just that `||` sometimes takes the shortcut of only evaluating the left side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before the loop, declare

```
int countOfScores = 0;
```

and inside the `if` block, write

```
countOfScores++;
```

Then you can print it out at the end.

Answer (score 2):

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
    if (scores[i] == 90 | scores[i] > 90) {
        System.out.println(scores[i]);
        count++
    }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Try this.

Answer (score 1):

Declare count variable to keep track of how many numbers satisfy given criteria.

```
int cnt=0;
for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
    if (scores[i] == 90 | scores[i] > 90) {

        cnt++;
    }
 System.out.println("Count : "+cnt);
}
```